# What it means for Disposable.dispose() to be idempotent?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

[RxJava documentation for Disposable.dispose](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/2.0.8/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html#dispose()) states

> Dispose the resource, the operation should be
> idempotent.

And according to the Wikipedia definition of [Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)

> Idempotence is the property of certain operations in mathematics and
> computer science whereby they can be applied multiple times without
> changing the result beyond the initial application.

Does it mean calling `dispose()` method on same `Disposable` multiple times will not have any additional effects? Will it dispose related resources only once?

That raises another question - what is the need for `isDisposed()` method then? Isn't it for checking if a disposable is disposed before disposing it again?

Comment: "Isn't it for checking if a disposable is disposed before disposing it again?" It's not just for that. Whether something is disposed could be useful for other things too, such as when you want to use it for something, but don't want to use an already-disposed object.

Comment: @Sweeper, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question.

> Does it mean calling dispose() method on same Disposable multiple
> times will not have any additional effects? Will it dispose related
> resources only once?

This is correct.
Regarding the `isDisposed()` method, its purpose is probably checking whether a resource has been disposed before you begin using it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's it.
2. `isDisposed()` will not prevent anyone to call `dispose()` twice. Think about calling a method that inconditionnaly calls `dispose()`...